# Best way to set up a redirect?

Tags: wordpress, http, http-redirect

I'm using wordpress. I have a post that has a pretty awkward url, like:

```
http://example.com/dogfood/why-do-dogs-like-bacon-i-will-investigate
```

I want to change the url to something more succinct, in hopes that it would improve my search results ranking:

```
http://example.com/dogfood/dogs-and-bacon
```

But this article is pretty popular now, and many third party sites have links pointing to the original url.

Is the best solution here to:

1. Duplicate the same post content at the new url.
2. Leave the old post as-is (the url will remain intact).
3. Set up a 301 redirect in my .htaccess file from the old url to the new url.

This way links to my old article will still work, but (hopefully) new searches for dog food bacon will start ranking my new url higher? Or can I simply delete the old post after I setup the redirect in my .htaccess file - no need to keep the old url around actually?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't count on a "more succinct" URL helping your rankings in this situation.

Comment: Ok but just pretending for a minute it does?

Comment: I personally prefer 301 redirect in .htaccess

Comment: Not an answer, but related: [Avoid duplicate content penalties and improve SEO]( http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/avoid-duplicate-content-penalties-and-improve-seo)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts:

1. [Duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359) is almost always a bad idea.
2. I think that leaving the old post URL intact is just fine. There's really no reason to change it. If what you want is to generate more traffic, there are other, more "kosher" ways of doing so: get other sites to link to your article or write an update to the article in a new post and add a link to the current article.  Besides, I think people are more likely to search for "Why do dogs like bacon?" than "dogs and bacon".
3. Technically a [301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) in your `.htaccess` file would be the best solution if you insist on changing the URL (which I discourage), but it would be a b*** to maintain for every post you want to redirect. Consider using a plugin that will do this for you, like [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/).